# data access through CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

This code is not working

```
select Distinct(country) + ' ' + city AS [COUNTRY] from cte_task where country_code Between 92 AND 93
```

This query isn't working properly. I want that country name should appear once and all the cities belong to that country should appear in a list after country name. e.g country Pakistan under country name all the cities of Pakistan should appear in a column.

Comment: Why the mysql tag?

Comment: Can you add the sql code for cte_task or show us a sample of what that data looks like please?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function!!! It's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and works on the whole selected rows. Write `SELECT DISTINCT country...` instead, to avoid confusion!!!

Comment: @wjs i cant understand what are you saying ?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this using FOR XML PATH.

```
select distinct tsk2.country
 , substring(
    (
        Select ', ' + tsk1.city AS [text()]
        From cte_task tsk1
        Where tsk1.country = tsk2.country
        ORDER BY tsk1.city
        For XML PATH ('')
    ), 2, 1000) [city]
from cte_task tsk2
where country_code Between 92 AND 93
```

[image: results]

The fact that you're using a CTE isn't really relevant - it will work the same way with a CTE as it would with a table.

Here is a SQL Fiddle demonstrating this query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9b8a02/19